# How to save a word into a dynamic list

Tags: c

So i managed to create a dynamic list, at the moment i can only insert a character into each node, i can remove a node and print the whole list, but i'm having a lot of troubles trying to change the list so that i can insert a dynamic array into each node and print it to a file, can someone give me some advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// self-referential structure                       
struct listNode {                                      
   char * data; // each listNode contains a character 
   struct listNode *nextPtr; // pointer to next node
}; 
typedef struct listNode ListNode; // synonym for struct listNode
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; // synonym for ListNode*
// prototypes
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value);
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value);
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr);
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr);
void instructions(void);
int main(void)
{ 
   ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; // initially there are no nodes
   char item; // char entered by user
   instructions(); // display the menu
   printf("%s", "? ");
   unsigned int choice; // user's choice
   scanf("%u", &choice);
   // loop while user does not choose 3
   while (choice != 3) { 
      switch (choice) { 
         case 1:
            printf("%s", "Enter a character: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &item);
            insert(&startPtr, item); // insert item in list
            printList(startPtr);
            break;
         case 2: // delete an element
            // if list is not empty
            if (!isEmpty(startPtr)) { 
               printf("%s", "Enter character to be deleted: ");
               scanf("\n%c", &item);
               // if character is found, remove it
               if (delete(&startPtr, item)) { // remove item
                  printf("%c deleted.\n", item);
                  printList(startPtr);
               } 
               else {
                  printf("%c not found.\n\n", item);
               } 
            } 
            else {
               puts("List is empty.\n");
            } 
            break;
         default:
            puts("Invalid choice.\n");
            instructions();
            break;
      } // end switch
      printf("%s", "? ");
      scanf("%u", &choice);
   } 
   puts("End of run.");
} 
// display program instructions to user
void instructions(void)
{ 
   puts("Enter your choice:\n"
      "   1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
      "   2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
      "   3 to end.");
} 
// insert a new value into the list in sorted order
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{ 
   ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create node
   if (newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
      newPtr->data = value; // place value in node
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...               
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node 
      }                                          
      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
   } 
} 
// delete a list element
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{ 
   // delete first node if a match is found
   if (value == (*sPtr)->data) { 
      ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr; // hold onto node being removed
      *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr; // de-thread the node
      free(tempPtr); // free the de-threaded node
      return value;
   } 
   else { 
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = *sPtr;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value) { 
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...  
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node  
      } 
      // delete node at currentPtr
      if (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         ListNodePtr tempPtr = currentPtr;
         previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         free(tempPtr);
         return value;
      } 
   } 
   return '\0';
} 
// return 1 if the list is empty, 0 otherwise
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{ 
   return sPtr == NULL;
} 
// print the list
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
{ 
   // if list is empty
   if (isEmpty(currentPtr)) {
      puts("List is empty.\n");
   } 
   else { 
      puts("The list is:");
      // while not the end of the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         printf("%c --> ", currentPtr->data);
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;   
      } 
      puts("NULL\n");
   } 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to read a *string* from the user, and make each node have a copy of those strings?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic array" in a node? What do you mean "print it to file" - change `printList` so that that prints to `FILE *` or what? I don't see the beginnings of either?

Comment: Yes exactly @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: For dynamic array i mean using heap allocation @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Then begin by *reading* a string. Dynamic allocation you already know (you do it now for the nodes), so the most important thing you have to remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and of course needs its space in the strings.

Comment: `newPtr->data = value` - that is a problem all on its own. If you want to store *dynamic strings* than all your single-char code management needs to be changed.

Comment: Got it! @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must turn warnings of your compiler on. It will tell you where you violate certain rules of C. For example, `newPtr->data = value;` should complain because `data` is a pointer but `value` is a char.

However, you should read a string from the user using the `"%s"` format specifier of `scanf` into a buffer that is large enough (or give bounds when reading), for example a buffer `char strbuf[256];`.

You pass this buffer to `insert`. Instead of assigning this `value` to `data`, you first allocate an new string and then copy the value to the new string:

```
newPtr->data = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
```

(This answer excludes any other bugs or problems your solution may have.)